# mongoimport from PowerShell

Tags: mongodb, powershell

I am trying to write a PowerShell script that watches a folder so that whenever a new JSON file is added to the folder or any of its sub folders a mongoimport command run to import that JSON file in a MongoDB. I wrote the following script, but it does not seem to do the job. I feel that I have a problem in the `Invoke-Command` part.

```
### SET FOLDER TO WATCH + FILES TO WATCH + SUBFOLDERS YES/NO
$watcher = New-Object System.IO.FileSystemWatcher
$watcher.Path = "C:\git\DataChain\UploadStation\to"
$watcher.Filter = "*.json"
$watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = $true
$watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = $true  

### DEFINE ACTIONS AFTER AN EVENT IS DETECTED
$action = {
    $path = $Event.SourceEventArgs.FullPath
    Invoke-Command -FilePath "C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.4\bin\mongoimport.exe" -ArgumentList (db myDB collection jsonFiles type json file $path)
}
### DECIDE WHICH EVENTS SHOULD BE WATCHED 
Register-ObjectEvent $watcher "Created" -Action $action
while ($true) {Start-Sleep 5}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `Invoke-Command` use the [call operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-3.0#special-operators) (`&`) and [splat](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting?view=powershell-3.0) the arguments:

```
$params = '--db', 'myDB',
          '--collection', 'jsonFiles',
          '--type', 'json',
          '--file', $Event.SourceEventArgs.FullPath
& "C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.4\bin\mongoimport.exe" @params
```